# static variable behavior in two different application

Tags: java

Two applications are running in a server. That means two EAR are present in server.
Now these two application has same jar within it. The jar has one static variable which is used by both applications.
First application_1 initializes that static variable to 50. Then application_2 initializes that variable to 100. 
So what is the value of static variable for application_1? Is it 50 or as it is the same jar file, so value should be overridden to 100.

If so,then please let me know why? As the application should be loaded in different memory location in the server and jar class will be loaded differently, is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't said which server you're using, but typically an application server has multiple classloaders involved - some shared, and some per-application. The Tomcat documentation has a [good explanation of its classloaders](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), for example.

If there's actually just *one* jar file, and it's in a location loaded by a shared classloader, then there's only one variable.

However, if the two applications each have their own copy of the jar file (for example if it really is embedded within the EAR file) - or it's in a common location but is loaded by a separate classloader for each application - then there'll be two variables.

Basically, each type in each classloader has its own separate static variables.

Of course, if you've got two completely separate server instances, when you're not just in different classloaders but different processes - at which point they will *certainly* be separate variables.

Comment: the OP says - *Two applications are running in a server. That means two EAR are present in server. Now these two application has same jar within it.* Would the same ClassLoader load the class in *two different applications*?

Comment: @TheLostMind: Probably not - but it depends on *exactly* what the OP means. If it really is a jar file embedded within the EAR file, then I would expect there to be two different classloaders. If it's actually just deployed with an assumption that the common jar file will be present, and that's deployed in a common location, then that could be a single classloader. I was hoping that by explaining the more general case, the OP could investigate their more specific case themselves. Will clarify.

Comment: When we make an EAR of a application then each copy of all jars which are used by this application is copied in this ear file. So if two application EAR exist in the server and if they are using same jar, then two EAR should have their own copy of jar. Is there any situation where two different EAR can share a single jar??                        If we put two / more application in server(application / tomcat) they should have their own context. Is there any point to place them common location??

Comment: @user2432330: Basically if your EARs depend on "system level" jar files already being present (which would make them less portable, mind you). But when you've got all the dependencies within the EAR files, any static variables should be appropriately separated. Consult your server documentation to check though.

Answer (score 0):

Each instance has it's own scope, so the second one can't change other one if you wanna share your variable you can use Data in Memory application such and Hazelcast.